# Linux - compile java file (hsqldb)

Tags: java, linux, hsqldb

```
javac db.java
# no errors
java -cp hsqldb.jar db
```

When I use the -cp option I get: "Error: Could not find or load main class db". My code works inside an ide but not in the console.

Comment: javac produces .class, not .jar files. cp must specify a folder.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined the classpath via `-cp` as simply containing the .jar file. You *also* need to declare the directory containing your .class file

e.g. if your `db.class` file is in the current directory (`.`)

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar:. db
```

(Unix) or

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar;. db
```

(Windows). Note the colon/semi-colon change between platforms.

Comment: I get a lot of bugs: http://pastebin.com/KVDqYydb

Comment: @user1429101 You should ask a new question. Now that your program is running you can ask for help debugging it. Don't forget to post code and ask a specific question.